# Как перезаписывать таблицу с нулевого id каждый раз, при запуске программы? peewee, SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, peewee

Предположим, есть некая программа, где я с помощью class_table.insert_many(elements).execute() могу вставить несколько элементов повторно. Проблема в том, что если я запускаю код повторно, я добавляю строки, которые уже были добавлены. Без использования peewee, cursor.executemany(query, elements) позволял вроде как переписывать таблицу с нуля.

Comment: да, естественно не нулевого, а первого id, имелл ввиду запись с первой строки

Comment: `DELETE FROM table`, после этого записывать данные? или я не так понял суть вопроса?,

Comment: Задайте себе главный вопрос: ЗАЧЕМ? На кой вам это понадобилось? Человека не должны интересовать айдишники, оставьте это компьютерам. Ведь вас же не интересует, по какому адресу в памяти компьютера размещаются объекты при их создании?

Comment: По делу. Как создана таблица? Используется autoincrement (счётчик глобальный)? Или счётчик локальный? / Как вариант, дропать таблицу и создавать заново. Но с глобальным счётчиком ничего не поможет...

Comment: Всмысле зачем? Чтобы при перезапуске проги, не добавлялись лишние строки

Comment: В общем кому интересно, добавил class_table.delete().execute() перед incert_many. Теперь после каждой инициализации таблицы как класса в программе, она обнуляется и только потом вставляются строки